# Problems with reading IO without blocking main thread

Tags: multithreading, rust, fltk

I have this code which runs inside `impl App` and specifically inside `fn launch()` exactly like [this example](https://github.com/fltk-rs/fltk-rs/blob/master/fltk/examples/editor.rs).

The output reading and writing has to occur in a separate thread so that the GUI doesn't freeze up. I have treid to work with MIO and tokio and subprocesses. With normal threads, I'm having issues with the borrow checker that I'm too much of a noob to solve. Firstly, here is a snippet of the program:

```rust
let mut child = Command::new(KOTLINC_PATH)
.arg("-script")
.arg(script_path)
.stdout(Stdio::piped())
// .stderr(Stdio::piped())
.spawn()
.expect("Could not execute script");

std::thread::spawn(move || {
    let out = BufReader::new(
        child.stdout.take().expect("Could not read from stdout."),
    );

    out.lines().for_each(|line| {
        self.output.terminals[0].append(line.unwrap().as_str());
        self.output.terminals[0].append("\n");
    });
});
```

And here are the errors:

```
borrowed data escapes outside of associated function
`self` escapes the associated function body here
main.rs(281, 23): `self` is a reference that is only valid in the associated function body
main.rs(281, 19): lifetime `'a` defined here
borrowed data escapes outside of associated function
argument requires that `'a` must outlive `'static`
```

I've read some articles about using Arc<Mutex<...>> but that requires changing the function signatures and honestly I'm also too much of a noob to figure this out. Would appreciate some help.

## Update

```rust
let mut child = Command::new(KOTLINC_PATH)
    .args(&["-script", script_path.clone().as_str()])
    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
    .spawn()
    .expect("Could not execute script");

let stdout = child.stdout.take().expect("Could not read from stdout.");

let output_clone = Arc::clone(&output);

let output_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
    let output_clone_ref = &output_clone; // Create a reference to the Arc<Mutex<String>> inside the closure

    for line in BufReader::new(stdout).lines() {
        let output_ref = output_clone_ref.lock().unwrap(); // Acquire a lock on the Mutex to modify the String

        (*output_ref).insert(line.unwrap().as_str());
        (*output_ref).insert("\n");
        drop(output_ref);
    }
});

// Gets stuck here.
output_thread.join().unwrap();
```

Comment: The normal way to get around this error is a scoped thread, but you can't use that, since it would defeat the purpose of unblocking your main loop. Alternatives are to make `self.output.terminals[0]` a `Arc<Mutex<…>>` and hand a clone of that to the thread (which should allow "the" function signature to stay the same - not sure which function signature you're talking about), or to use a `std::sync::mpsc::channel`.

Comment: Ok so I've moved this function out of the impl and made output just a String for simplicity. I tried implementing the Arc<Mutex<...>> way but I get the error "use of moved value: `output_clone`
move occurs because `output_clone` has type `Arc<Mutex<String>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait". I've updated the question with my attempt.

Comment: Actually, I got it to work but now my main thread gets blocked waiting for the join call. Again updated question. You can also find full code on: https://github.com/noureldinali/kotliscript

Comment: Creating a single thread and then immediately joining it is pointless in most cases, join is literally there to wait for the thread's completion. What happens if you just don't `join`?

Comment: Yup that worked thanks. I did try that before and got an error and assumed it was because I removed the join but it was a different error. Must just be tired. Thanks a lot! I assume I should handle the joins on closing of my program? Although right now it doesn't complain so unsure but I know thats how it's done in C.

Comment: From the Rust side, it's ok to not call join ever. But I don't know what the `Command` you spawned does when its parent process (and stdio pipes) go away. So, you might want to.

Comment: [`Child`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html) doesn't implement `Drop` so the spawned process will just keep on running. @Caesar

Comment: @cafce25: It doesn't matter whether `Child` implements `Drop`, the question is what happens if process exits while the thread owning `child` still lives, which means `child` will never be dropped ([cf](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f4a121fccc704eba65bcceeafcffc031)). I think the child process will still get a SIGPIPE/errors on writing to stdout. That may well cause it to exit. (I'll ignore OSses where child processes can't outlive parents and assume linux.)

Comment: @Orcadeum I think you could get away with just `thread::spawn(|| { let output = Command::new(KOT).args([…]).output().unwrap(); assert!(output.status.success(), "TODO: error handling"); *output_clone.lock().unwrap() = String::from_utf8(output.stdout).unwrap(); }):`

Comment: @Caesar Would that not read from stdout in one go? I need the program to basically stream stdout and stderr live to the gui. Also why did you put the command in the thread? Is it so that it dies with the thread?

Comment: Also with regards to reading from stderr at the same time, should i merge stderr and stdout together or is there a good way to iterate over each new line in two BufReaders?

Comment: Ah, didn't know you wanted to stream output. And I think the standard answer to "merge stdout and stderr" is "use a pty" ([this crate](https://docs.rs/pty-process/latest/pty_process/) looks nice), but I don't really know. You might want to ask a separate question (or search whether somebody already has).